# How do i sync variables across threads? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Lets say i have A) Global variable B) Local variable but another thread has a ptr to it

Lets say i have this code

```
thread2(&localVar);//now thread2 can modify it
localVar=0;
globalVar=0;
while(1){
    mutex.lock();
    cout << (globalVar && localVar ? "Both true" : "fail");
    mutex.unlock();
    Sleep(1000)
}
```

Is this correct and safe? I can't remember. If it is my question is how does C++ know that localVar and globalVar may have been modified? If you say its because of mutex lock/unlock then my question is why? When calling any functions does C++ believe variables may have been modified and need to be reloaded into the register?

If this isn't safe then what makes it unsafe? (I suspect if it isnt then only localVar is unsafe), how do i correct it?

Comment: Does your second thread also take the same mutex before modifying the variables?

Comment: Please provide complete code, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: `When calling any functions does C++ believe variables may have been modified and need to be reloaded into the register?` Whatever has to be done to make mutexes work is done. If that's what it takes, then that's what's done. (What actually needs to be done can be platform-specific. It may involve invalidating register contents prior to all mutex operations, it may not.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I doubt compilers check and do special things for that function/class because its called mutex

Comment: @acidzombie24: It depends on the compiler. For some, nothing special is needed. They do it for all external functions. For some, specific "[clobbers](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3)" are needed on the functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a lot more complicated then it really is. Your responsibility is to make sure **no conflicting accesses to a variable ever happen**.

Definition: two accesses to a given memory location **conflict** *iff* they can happen concurrently and **at least one is a write access**.

So:

- two writes to the same memory location = bad
- a read and a write to the same memory location = bad

To ensure this never happens, you can use `mutex`, or you design your program so that variables shared between threads are only read. There are many other possible strategies.

If I understand your incomplete code correctly: `localVar` is modified concurrently in two threads. **The behavior is not defined. Anything can happen.**

Comment: The criteria for "at least one write access" doesn't hold when/if there are multiple values involved.  If you want to present the current state of the "set of values" properly, you'll want that mutex guarding it.

Comment: By "doesn't hold" I should be more clear: it's not sufficient when considering a set of values that need to be looked at as a whole.  If you allow unrestricted read-access, you may get one modified and the other "not yet updated" to reflect current state - they're out-of-sync.

Comment: @RichardSitze Sorry, I still don't get it; can you provide a code example?

Comment: Example: a writer-thread sets a time, position, and velocity - these values are bound to each other.  You don't want a reader-thread to read time `t3`, position at time `t2`, and velocity at time `t3`.  So your writer-thread will use a mutex to protect the update to the set of bound values (time, position, velocity), and your reader-thread will use the same mutex to protect it's read of the set of values.

Comment: @RichardSitze This example illustrates the distinction between language constraints and domain constraints: the language only says that each individual variable (time, position, and velocity) must be protected from conflicting access (possibly by 3 different `mutex` variables: time_mutex, position_mutex, and velocity_mutex) but the high level constraint implies that you can only have one mutex for all three variables.

Comment: Yes.  And the coders responsibility is to address both to obtain correct results.  In the original question, there are two shared variables globalVar and localVar - so I see this as is relevant to determining the correctness of any response.

Answer (score 0):

> It this correct and safe?

No.

Fix: Initialize localVar and globalVar before creating your second thread.

That you've exposed a localVar (on local stack? local var suggests on stack in scope) to another thread is troublesome.  If this localVar is on the stack, then just be sure that you don't let it drop out of scope.

Are you using the same mutex on the other thread, to protect read/write access?  If yes, then this is moving towards safe.

It's not a question of "does C++ know that localVar and globalVar may have been modified?":  C++ doesn't know.  For this situation, as described, it's all about using the mutex to properly protect all access to all shared values.  The mutex, if used by both threads, allows only ONE thread at a time to get past it, into the protected code.  Any other thread trying to lock the mutex will "stop & wait" until the lock is released.

So you're on the right track by surrounding your reads of the pair of values by the mutex.

> When calling any functions does C++ believe variables may have been modified and need to be reloaded into the register?

As a general rule, yes.

Comment: In my example, localVar and globalVar is assumed to be initialized or constructed already. The other thread(s) are assumed to be correct. So i'm focusing on this thread. In this thread/example the while loop is forever and going out of scope has nothing to do with thread/question so ignore that. Yes i would be. But i don't understand how C++ would know to sync the variables at that point. Another example is assuming my code allows one of the two vars to be outdated (it can wait until the next loop) why cant i do `Flush()` instead of a mutex lock (and no unlock)? Would it know the var has been

Comment: changed? (assuming the var is not marked as volatile). Lets say i have no mutex will this thread ever see the update from another thread? and if not then why does lock allow it to see? These were the types of things i wanted to know when asking this question

Comment: @acidzombie24 you set localVar and globalVar both to 0 immediately prior to the while loop - that looked like init code, and it is unguarded.  May or may not cause you an issue, but it is bad form at best.

Comment: @acidzombie24 you'll see changes without the mutex.  See my comments to curiousguy's response.

Comment: @acidzombie24 your statement " i don't understand how C++ would know to sync the variables" suggests what might be confusing you.  C++ is NOT syncing variables - it only creates one copy and you are choosing to SHARE them between two concurrent threads.  Mutex is about allowing you to restrict access to a portion of your code - in this case reading or writing to a shared variable.  Proper use of the mutex allows you to coordinate via this restricted access.

Answer (score 0):

I think that first time your get address of the local variable it become volatile and all reads and writes is performing with the memory.